# Why is this Linux process running so slow?

Tags: performance, top, strace

I've got a Python process on my Ubuntu 19.04 system that doesn't seem to be memory starved, yet is running a lot slower than I expect.  The system has 96 GB of RAM plus 96 GB of swap.  This process is heavily compute bound and is the only thing on the system with a substantial memory footprint.

`top` looks like this:

```
top - 04:26:15 up 18 days,  6:26,  1 user,  load average: 1.00, 1.02, 1.23
Tasks: 328 total,   1 running, 327 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.7 us,  0.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 96.1 id,  2.5 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
GiB Mem :     94.3 total,      0.5 free,     86.1 used,      7.8 buff/cache
GiB Swap:    104.0 total,     97.5 free,      6.5 used.      7.4 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
15182 baccala   20   0  117.6g  85.2g   3736 D  20.3  90.3  32:06.77 python2
```

What I really don't understand is how this meshes with what `strace` is telling me:

```
baccala@blade1:~/helium$ timeout 10s strace -cw -p 15182
strace: Process 15182 attached
strace: Process 15182 detached
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.055781          86       645           brk
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.055781                   645           total
```

Since over a ten second interval, only 55 ms were spent in the system call, how come only 20% CPU utilization with a 'D' status?

I'm reading this like `top` is telling me that the program is spending lots of time in the kernel, but `strace` is telling me the opposite.  Plus the system has hardly touched its swap space, and I've still got several GB in buff/cache, so it doesn't seem like it should be out of memory, even though it's using a lot.

The process ran at 100% CPU until it hit about 80 GB resident set size, then it started doing this.  Also, I didn't have swap configured when the program started, but added it with `swapon` once it became clear that it might run out of RAM.

Can anybody explain what's going on here?

**Update**

I've now become convinced that the process is starved for memory.  What I didn't consider is that `strace` only shows delay in the system calls, but doesn't show delay during page faults.  And the process *is* swapping, as `iotop` shows:

```
 TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN      IO    COMMAND
15182 be/4 baccala  1409.08 K/s    0.00 B/s 92.57 %  0.00 % python2
15182 be/4 baccala  1649.00 K/s    0.00 B/s 91.62 %  0.00 % python2
15182 be/4 baccala  1245.74 K/s    0.00 B/s 94.78 %  0.00 % python2
15182 be/4 baccala  1904.57 K/s    0.00 B/s 90.60 %  0.00 % python2
15182 be/4 baccala  1904.63 K/s    0.00 B/s 88.55 %  0.00 % python2
```

What I still don't understand is why this behavior started when `top`'s `RES` field was still 16 GB short of the machine's available RAM, and there was still 10 GB listed for `buff/cache`.  There's still something I don't understand about how Linux is managing memory here.

Comment: `iotop` shows the process is spending lots of time swapping in.  Swap ins wouldn't affect system call time.  Perhaps the program is running slow because it's waiting for pages to come in from the disk.

Comment: is this a process that is amenable to parallelisation?   if so, maybe could break it into several smaller jobs (perhaps one per cpu core - but note that all threads will be competing for the same IO bandwidth. and RAM) and run them in parallel.

Comment: @cas, yes, I'm starting to think about how to break this task down into pieces that fit into memory.

Comment: Alternatively, you might be able to get significantly better performance by managing your memory usage directly (that is, never going above the system's total RAM, but explicitly moving data in and out of memory from your own code).  This is, for example, how good text editors handle files that are larger than system memory.